# iOS application, How to know which account was used to buy app in ios appstore?

Tags: ios

I want to know which account was used to buy my app in ios appstore. So my question is when a user buy an app, is there any receipt file (or something else) store in ios device? Thanks

Comment: if you ask apple to send you notifications while using an id with iTunes it send you receipt type email on purchase/free download of every app with that account. Otherwise you will not be able to do that.

Comment: Apple does not allow to collect such personal information, according their privacy-policy. if you need the user's email address, you need to ask it from them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Receipt validation on iOS 7 to get some purchase details.  The fields in the receipt are listed in the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW2)

The identity of the purchasing user is not one of them.  If you have in-app purchase then you can correlate the purchase with an identity on your own backend, if you have one, but you cannot do this for the actual app purchase and you cannot access the purchaser's Apple ID.